# Appium and android stock browser

Tags: android-webview, google-chrome-devtools, samsung-mobile, appium, android-browser

I have Samsung device with stock browser that called Internet.
The device is over 4.4 version.
I'm trying to remote debug the stock browser on a real device without success.
Already succeeded to remote debug chrome.

Is it possible on a real device and not on emulator?

Answer (score 1):

## The problem is just Samsung's stock browser

Hi!, Appium started to work with Android's stock browser (named.. **Browser**) since v1.3, the actual problem is the Samsung stock browser isn't **Browser**, it's **Internet**! These both apps are different (shame on Samsung!, not Appium guys fault). All other Android distributions that stock browser is **Browser** are working fine with Appium >= v1.3 as I've said before.

Emulator stock browser is Browser, that's why it's working for you on Emulator!

## Why Appium doesn't work with Samsung's stock browser?

Appium are built to work with Chromium WebView (present on **Chrome** and **Browser**) , and **Internet** does not have it. So it doesn't work with Appium now, and probably won't work never, as Appium's maintainers does not have any interest to do the automation outside Chromium WebView. See this issue for more information: https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/4509

## Ok, but how do I use Appium with Samsung devices?

So, the only solution is installing Chrome into your samsung device.

If you can't access the store to install the Chrome app, you can download and install manually the Chrome APK into your device (or other browser that uses Chromium webview, such as Chromium and ContentShell).

PS: ContentShell is basically only Chromium webview, without favorites, bookmarks and other common browser stuff, so it's pretty good for Appium testing.